Manually refresh pivot table in order to reveal row field
wrote a macro that creates a pivot table base off a data set. The code runs smoothly, except the pivot table created only shows one value in first row field where there are other values in the first row field and other row fields.
By one value, i mean distinct value in the row field. There are many but it only shows one.
I need to manually refresh the pivot table so it shows all all distinct values in two row fields.
oddly enough, i enabled the grand total and the number stays the same and is correct.
these are my code. copied from internet pretty sandarded.
delete worksheet then create new
use Lr and Lc to define data range
'Creating Pivot Table
    Set Psheet = Worksheets(Pvt_shName)
    Set Dsheet = Worksheets(ProjectName.End(xlToRight).Value)
    
    Pvt_LR = Dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Pvt_LC = Dsheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`
'Set Range
    Set PRange = Dsheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Pvt_LR, Pvt_LC)
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
    
    'Creat Pivot Table
    Set Pvt = PCache.CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=Psheet.Cells(1, 1),   TableName:="PO&CO_Tracking")
    'Row
    With Psheet.PivotTables("PO&CO_Tracking")
        With .PivotFields("Work Type")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Vendor")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
    End With
    'Value
    With Psheet.PivotTables("PO&CO_Tracking")
        With .PivotFields("Approved Purchase Orders (A)")
            .Orientation = xlDataField

            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Approved Change Orders (B)")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Total Committed (C = A + B)")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 3
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Invoiced (D)")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 4
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Balance Remaining (E = C - D)")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 5
        End With
    End With

    'Format
    'Format Pivot Table
    Psheet.PivotTables("PO&CO_Tracking").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
    Psheet.PivotTables("PO&CO_Tracking").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium14"
    
    'Show in Tabular form
    Psheet.PivotTables("PO&CO_Tracking").RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    
    Psheet.PivotTables("PO&CO_Tracking").RefreshTable



is there a way to correct this, so that i don't need to manually refresh the table?

This issue arises because everytime you run your marcro, a new pivot gets created and with that your selections from the previous one gets overwritten.
'Creat Pivot Table
Set Pvt = PCache.CreatePivotTable(tabledestination:=Psheet.Cells(1, 1),   TableName:="PO&CO_Tracking")
'Row

In case you just want to update the contents of your pivot, you could add a quick check, whether your desired table already exists and therefore you just need to update the contents or if the macro should actually create a new pivot.
An example of this would be adding in somethink anlong the lines of:
Dim Pvt As PivotTable
' Check if the Pivot Table exists
On Error Resume Next
Set Pvt = Psheet.PivotTables(PvtName)
On Error GoTo 0
' If Pivot Table doesn't exist, create it
If Pvt Is Nothing Then
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
    Set Pvt = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:=PvtName)
Else
    ' Update the Pivot Table's data source
    Pvt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
    Pvt.RefreshTable
End If

You might need to readjust this code before using it as I didn't want to build a full Excel to test it, but I hope the code at least helps you find out whats the issue here. Also as a hint for the future, I found getting the gist of whats wrong or already fixed code by asking the "Code Copilot" GPT pretty helpful.  Good luck fixing!

Hello, I did what you suggested, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.
I tested it on a newly downloaded file and the initial pivot table has the same problem. Does it has sth to do with my excel formatting?

Don't need to bother you anymore, i made a mistake and found the solution.
to boost speed, i turned off screen_updating and displayalerts at the beginning of the code.
When i add a refresh after i turn these functions back on, pivot tables shows all the row fields.
